# Implementing authentication in PHP F3 framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

What's the recommended way of doing the auth checks?  I really don't want to duplicate the auth checks all over the code in every single route, and while they have the before/after route hooks if you use objects, I would still like to minimize how often I'm repeating that code.

Is there a global 'before/after' route hook for *everything* and/or what's the recommended way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to duplicate the auth checks in every single route, then you'd better create a base class extended by every single controller class:

```
abstract class secureController {

  function beforeRoute($f3,$params) {
    //...
    if ($auth_failed)
      $f3->error(401);//or 403
  }

}

class controller1 extends secureController {

  function route1() {}
  function route2() {}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds perfect.  I just wasn't sure what my options were since I'm new to F3.